# В чем проблема с этим Promise?

Tags: javascript

почему возвращается catch?

```js
function getPost(cb){
    console.log('Получаем список постов...');
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'curr.json');
        request.onreadystatechange(() => {
            if(request.readyState === 4){
                const response = JSON.parse(request.response);
                cb(response);
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        })
        request.send();
    })
    return promise;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    getPost((cb) => {
        console.log(cb);
    })
    .then(() => {console.log('Посты загружены успешно!')})
    .catch(() => {console.log('Что-то пошло не так!')})
})
```

Comment: `readystatechange` срабатывает несколько раз и не сразу со стейтом `4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getPost(cb){
    console.log('Получаем список постов...');
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'curr.json');
        // Используем событие onload, раз вам нужно именно окончание запроса
        request.onload(() => {
            const response = JSON.parse(request.response);
            cb(response);
            resolve();
        });
        // Обработка ошибки
        request.onerror = reject;
        request.send();
    })
    return promise;
}
```

**Почитать**: 
[События xmlHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest#polnyy-spisok-sobytiy)